# How can I horizontally and vertically center an <img> in a <div>?

Tags: css, html, web-standards

I don't want to center a div, I want the contents of a div to be centered.  I would like horizontal and vertical alignment.

Sorry, if this is too easy or whatever, but this is kind of a hassle to get it right.

Grae

I am using IE7

Comment: I am using IE7, but honestly for something this simple, you would think it would work for all browsers.  I know it won't, but it would make sense that it would.

Comment: Do you want to align text or block elements? Text can be centered using `text-align: center`. Centering block elements can be a bit trickier.

Comment: I am trying to vertically and horizontally align am img in a div

Answer (score 2):

If you know the height and width of your image, position it absolutely, set top/left to 50% and margin-top/left to *negative* half the height/width of your image.

```
#foo {
    position:relative; /* Ensure that this is a positioned parent */
}
#foo img {
    width:240px;
    height:200px;
    position:absolute;
    left:50%;
    top:50%;
    margin-left:-120px;
    margin-top:-100px;
}
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/Zd2pz/

Answer (score 2):

I know you've said that dont want to center a div but to achieve your requirement in a cross browser way would be easier using a jquery plugin and a fake div that contains your element to be centered.

I have successfully centered almost anything using this [very small plugin](http://www.alexandremagno.net/jquery/plugins/center/) that can center any block element.

The only other way I know are the answer that you already received from @simshaun & @Prhogz

EDIT: As per comment request

Include the script in your head tag

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%: Url.Content( "~/_assets/js/jquery.center.min.js" )%>"></script>
```

Now if you have a DIV that you want to center inside your markup simply use it as

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#myDIV").center({ vertical: false });
});
```

Comment: i voted up for you, but let me ask you to explain how to insert it in html code, i am very week in jquery

Answer (score 1):

although the following is **obsolete**, it still works for almost all browsers

```
<center>
<div>
your html
</div>
</center>
```

however, visit this link

http://www.110mb.com/forum/vertical-horizontal-alignment-of-image-within-div-t31709.0.html

Answer (score 0):

For horizontal alignment, use `text-align:center;`

For vertical alignment, see for example the [W3 style guide](http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center.html#block)

Comment: Be cautious if you implement vertical centering as the W3 example shows. IE<=7 does not support `display: table-cell`.

Comment: @simshaun Yes, this sample does not work with IE8 in IE7 compat mode.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the inner element's height beforehand,

CSS:

```
.container {
    text-align: center; /* Center horizontally. */

    /* For demo only */
    border: 1px solid #000;
    height: 500px;
    margin: 20px;
    width: 700px;
}

.container img {
    margin-top: -167px;
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <img src="http://farm6.static.flickr.com/5004/5270561847_7223069d5e.jpg" width="500" height="334" alt="">
</div>
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Hs5uw/)